# How can I use d3.js to mutate svg in a variable instead of from the DOM

Tags: reactjs, svg, d3.js

I'm embedding a react component into an MDX document like this:

```
// index.mdx

import MyComponent from './diagram'
const src = `
graph TD;
  A[foo] --> B[bar]
`

Behold! a Mermaid diagram:
<MyComponent id="diag" content={src}/>
```

The component looks like this:

```
// diagram.js

class FooDiag extends Component {

  // code that populates this.state.svg goes here

  render() {
    if (!this.state.svg) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>
    }

    // confirms that the root of the svg has id="diag"
    console.log(this.state.svg)

    // doesn't work
    // var modifedSvg = d3.select("#diag").append("circle")
    //      .attr("cx", 10)
    //      .attr("cy", 10)
    //      .attr("r", 5)
    //      .attr("fill", "red")
    //
    // return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: modifiedSvg }} />

    return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.svg }} />
  }
```

(I got the pattern above [here](https://www.developmentsindigital.com/2017-10-26-mermaid-in-react))

My goal is to generate the svg with [Mermaid](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/) and then modify it with [d3](https://d3js.org/) before displaying it on the page.  The code above works:  The diagram does show up on the page.

But I only know how to make d3 select from the DOM.  I think that the problem with my commented code above is that `this.state.svg` is not yet part of the DOM, so d3 can't find it.  I imagine that there is a way to slurp up the svg from the variable instead, but d3 is a big place and I don't know what to search for.

How can I make the commented d3 code in my snippet above place the red circle in my diagram?

I tried this:

```
var d3svg = d3.select("#diag").html(this.state.svg)
d3svg.append("circle")
  .attr("cx", 10)
  .attr("cy", 10)
  .attr("r", 5)
  .attr("fill", "red")
// console.log(d3svg.???)
```

I don't know if it's working.  I can't tell because I don't know how to get the actual svg out of the `d3svg` selection object.

Thanks in advance for any help.  Also, sorry if there are irrelevant details above--I'm new to the front end.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting by `#diag` gives me something other than the toplevel svg element, which makes it tricky to get that element back as a string.  Selecting by `svg` instead gives me just that element.

This did the trick:

```
var d3svg = d3.select("svg").html(this.state.svg)
d3svg.select("g[id^='flowchart-A']").append("circle")
   .attr("cx", 10)
   .attr("cy", 10)
   .attr("r", 5)
   .attr("fill", "red")

return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: d3svg.node().innerHTML }} />
```